# Matching Integral with Int (Haskell)

Tags: haskell

I'm new to Haskell and I'm trying to get the length of a number in base 10 so I created length' function:

```
length' :: (Integral a) => a -> a
length' a = length $ show a
```

But Haskell gives me "Couldn't match type" error because `length` returns Int. I don't get why it gives me an error since Int an instance of Integral...

Comment: Because your output is `Int` and here you make a claim that the type can be *any* `Integral` type.

Comment: You can use `fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b` to convert from an `Int` to any `Num` (and all `Integral`s are `Num`s so that works).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write something like:

```
length' :: (Integral a) => a -> a
```

it means that the function will work for *any* `a` where `Integral a` holds. So that means that a programmer that uses `length'` could decide to use it as: `length' :: Integer -> Integer`. Since `length` however does not return an `Integer` (but an `Int`), Haskell can not provide such function `length'`.

Your function has another problem as well: you call `show` on `a`. This means that `a` has to be an instance of the `Show` class. So you should add a type constraint `Show a`. There is no need to restrict to `Integral a`, since you can use the function for everything that is `Show`. So the type signature should be:

```
length' :: Show a => a -> Int
length' = length . show
```

If you want to give the user the freedom to use any `Num n` as output type, you can use the [**`genericLength :: Num n => [a] -> n`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html#v:genericLength) function:

```
import Data.List(genericLength)

length' :: (Show a, Num n) => a -> n
length' = genericLength . show
```

Comment: Oh, thanks! So in mathematical terms, all Haskell functions must be bijective?

Comment: @Miksu: no, a bijection guarantees that all input maps to output and all output has one input element. This is not always the case: you can decide to ignore certain patterns (this is however not recommended), and furthermore negative output here has no matching input (given `length` does not overflow).

Answer (score 1):

`Int` is an instance of integral, but so is, for example, `Integer`. Your signature is `a -> a` (where `a` is an `Integral`), meaning the type of the result must be the same as the type of the input. So if you apply `length'` to an `Int`, the result should be an `Int` according to your signature, and if you apply it to an `Integer`, the result should be an `Integer`.

Since `length` produces an `Int` as its result, the result of `length'` will also always be an `Int`, which contradicts your signature.

One fix would be to change your signature to `Integral a => a -> Int` (or the more general `Show a => a -> Int`) or to add a call to `fromIntegral` to convert your `Int` to a number of the appropriate type.